# Derivative of terminal state w.r.t. the inital conditions.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, perturbation-theory

Let $x\in R^n$ and consider the system

$$
\dot{x}=f(t,x) \;\;\mbox{with}\;\; x(0)=x_0
$$
and suppose that we know it's exact or very accurate solution $x(t)$ for the time interval $[0,T]$.

I'm asking myself how to approximate the value of a second solution at time $T$, say $y(T)$, of the same system for small variations of the initial conditions, i.e.

$$
\dot{y}=f(t,y) \;\;\mbox{with}\;\; y(0)=x_0 + \epsilon v
$$

for do that I think that it is necessary to compute the derivative of the state
w.r.t. the initial conditions, so, lets write each component of $x$ as $x^i$, the same for $f$.

$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial x_0^j} \dot{x}^i = \frac{\partial f^i}{\partial x^k} \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial x_0^j}
$$

for shorthand, I call $\psi^i_j = \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x_0^j}$. So the solution of the system
$$
\dot{\psi}_j^i = \left[\frac{\partial f^i}{\partial x^k}\right]_{x=x(t)} \psi^k_j
$$
and the equation
$$
y^i(t) = x^i(t) + \psi^i_j v^j
$$
should give the answer to my question for all $t$. Is that true?, second, what should be the initial conditions for $\psi_j^i$?, and third, it is that procedure correct for the variation of the solution w.r.t. other parameters if they depends on time?

Comment: The only error I can see is your final interpretation $y^i=x^i+\psi^i_j v^j$. $\psi_j^i$ only tells you what the *infinitesimal* change is to $x^i$ given an *infinitesimal* change to $x_0^j$ (i.e. $\epsilon\to 0$). But crucially your perturbation is finite so, in general, chaotic effects will cause this solution to fail.