# Sensitivity of path integral w.r.t. initial state

Tags: partial-derivative, stochastic-integrals, optimal-control

I'm trying to figure out how the value of a path integral depends on the initial condition (starting point) of the path.

**Part1:**

Consider the state variable $x(t)$ that is governed by an ODE
$$\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t))$$
with some initial condition. This defines our path in time.

Let's say I have a path integral, for example a cost-to-go $C(x_t,t)$ that evaluates how much cost will be accumulated until a final time $t_f$ for a path starting at $x_t$ at time $t$ and governed by the ODE above:
$$ C(x_t,t) = \int_t^{t_f} g(x(\tau)) \; d\tau \qquad \text{given: } x(t)=x_t, \; \dot{x}(t) = f(x(t))$$

**Now my question**: What is ${\partial C(x_t,t) \over \partial x_t} $, i.e., the sensitivity of the cost-to-go w.r.t. the starting state?

I'm having troubles figuring this out because I don't know how to formalize the dependence of future states on $x_t$.

**Part2:**

How does the answer change when we consider a stochastic path (random walk) instead
$$dx = f(x,t) dt + \sigma(x,t) dw$$
where $dw$ is standard Brownian motion and the cost-to-go is now an expectation over all paths that start at $x_t$ at time $t$:
$$ C(x_t,t) = {\mathbb E}_{x_t} \left[ \int_t^{t_f} g(x(\tau)) \; d\tau \right] \qquad \text{given: } x(t)=x_t $$

I've tried to apply some Ito calculus rules here but I'm getting stuck again...

*Possibly related questions:*

[Derivative of terminal state w.r.t. the inital conditions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875060/derivative-of-terminal-state-w-r-t-the-inital-conditions)

[Compute partial derivative w.r.t initial condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114272/compute-partial-derivative-w-r-t-initial-condition)

Comment: The first part looks more like calculus of variations than stochastic stuff. Do you know the form of $g?$

Comment: yep, the first part is not stochastic, but the ODE for $x(t)$ is already known, so I think this is not a variational problem. $g$ can be an arbitrary continuous and differentiable function in my problem

Comment: If $x$ is already determined by the ODE and therefore fixed, then I'm not sure I see the point in calculating that sensitivity. It's really only going to be sensitive to changes in $g,$ since that's all you're allowing to vary. You can probably use the chain rule and the Euler-Lagrange equations to get at a solution to the first problem.

Comment: I'm varying the initial state $x_t$. $g$ is fixed.

Comment: For part 1, you might be forced to determine the sensitivities numerically. Since $C = \int g dt$, if you can't solve the integral analytically then it'd be easiest to evaluate $C$ by quadrature over $x(t)$. Then you can determine $dC/dx(t_0)$ by finite difference wrapped around the quadrature. This isn't variational calculus since $g$ is only dependent on $x$ and $t$. That is, there is no coordinate $h$ such that $h' = g(x,h)$. I have no idea how to extend this for part 2, however. If this is a suitable answer, let me know and I can write it out in an actual answer with more detail.

Comment: I meant to say this isn't a full-blown calculus of variations problem but can't edit my comment. Some explicit dependencies are eliminated so that simplifies the problem down somewhat. You can still absolutely apply EL equations.